# Solve method in wolfram mathematica

Tags: methods, wolfram-mathematica

[image]

I have a error when I used Solve method for that system. If it is a wrong method that I used, is there another method for solving this system?

Comment: looks like you have the `MatrixForm` of the lists in there. `MatrixForm` is strictly for output format and can not be further used in other calculations.

Comment: yes agentp I used MatrixForm. but did'nt the solve method want matrix?

Comment: show the actual code, not an image

Answer (score 0):

```
Mmatrix = MatrixForm[M];
Ggamma = MatrixForm[\[Gamma]];
Slvc1c2c3 = Solve[Mmatrix.( {{x},{y},{z}} ) == Ggamma, {x, y, z}]
```

agentp codes are above which  I used for solving Ax=b system.

Comment: as  I said, do not use `MatrixForm`

Comment: ok agentp when I dont use MatrixForm in Solve method, how can I write Mmatrix as a matrix form? or it solves without matrix form. Is it true?

Comment: I tried without MatrixForm, but it gives {} result. Is there any example for solving matrix systems with Solve method, yo know?

Comment: edit your question to include the actual code (the new version without `MatrixForm` appearing anywhere ).  Don't make folks who want to help retype anything.  (My guess your system simply has no solution).

Comment: Agentp thank you so much and sorry for incomplete question I had to write actual code. I found the error that the system has no solution :)